# How do I sign my code using a MD5 Password?

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I'm a bit new to answering questions, so bear with me here. And i've read posts, and i've seen that mysql_ is not being used anymore. I know that, so don't tell me not to use it.

Anyhow, I've got this code, and whenever I try to sign up using it, the password isn't hashed in MD5. I've removed the

```
$mdhash = md5('$name');
```

because I want your help.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    include('./dbconnect/global.php');

    if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
    $comment = mysql_escape_string (trim ($_POST['username']));
    $id = 0;
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
        if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
            if ($_POST['username']=="telamon" or $_POST['username']=="brick") {
                die("This username is banned");
            }
                $name = mysql_escape_string (trim ($_POST['password']));
                $mdehash = md5($name);
                $email = mysql_escape_string (trim ($_POST['email']));
                $picture = $_POST['def'];
                $tweet = 'NoTweetsTweeted';
                $g = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='".$comment."'") or die(mysql_error());

                if (mysql_num_rows($g) >= 1) {
                    $errMsg = "<p style='color:#999999;'>That username is already registerd!</p>";
                }else {
                    if ( preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i", $comment) ) { 
                    $sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO admin (id,username,password,date,picture,email,twitter) VALUES ('".$id."','".$comment."','".$name."','".$date."','".$picture."','".$email."','".$tweet."')");
                    header('location: home.php');
                    }else
                    $errMsg = "<p style='color:#999999;'>Please fill all fields!</p>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

So, if I could get some help with this, that'd be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use md5 but a salted hash using a more secure algorithm instead. Also you **must** use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `mysql_escape_string` - or even better, **use PDO or mysqli** instead of the deprecated mysql api.

Comment: What _is_ your question?

Comment: Where are you using `$mdehash`? You define it as `md5($name)` but later use `$name` in your `INSERT` statement directly.

Comment: **tl;dr;** *use an existing library*. This isn't a new problem, and many people get it *very wrong*. It's very easy to get security incorrect, especially when *not* really understanding how it works. There are *many* other duplicates showing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the single quote in this statement.

```
$mdhash = md5('$name');
```

It should be:

```
$mdhash = md5($name);
```

The single quotes cause the dollar sign to be taken literally and as a result $name is not a variable anymore but a literal string.

Comment: you could also mention why `md5("$name")` would work but be bad; i think it'd somewhat fit into the answer to his question. the asker seems to be a beginner and he'll likely stumble upon that kind of "code"

Comment: Actually I saw your comment and figured that covered it. Hopefully when PHP5.5 comes out everyone will ditch the old tutorials and start using the new password API.

Comment: @JohnConde Considering people still "suggest" the hackish `mysql_real_escape_string` (or ignore SQL injection issues entirely) .. I think not. Too much bad junk on/in PHP ..

Comment: You also still believe in santa, don't you? :) I don't think all the crap out there will ever disappear or finally end up not being used. If PHP decides to ditch all the crap (mainly the mysql extension) you'll just see new questions here how to fix that "unknown function" error...

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're passing `$name` into the SQL Database instead of `$mdehash` in your query.

I'd also change the variable names to better match their actual usage.  They're slightly confusing.